# Open external link on ion-tab

Tags: ionic-framework, external-links

I have no idea how to open an external browser for the app. I already fixed it under , it works fine as the code below:

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-right" id="boironMedicineFinder2-list-item1368" href-inappbrowser="https://www.boironusa.com/medicines/" onClick="openExternal(this)">Boiron Shop
  <i class="icon ion-ios-cart-outline"></i>
```

However, when I put , it does not work for the code below:

```
<ion-tab class="item-icon-right" id="boironMedicineFinder2-list-item1368" href-inappbrowser="https://www.boironusa.com/medicines/" onClick="openExternal(this)">Boiron Shop
  <i class="icon ion-ios-cart-outline"></i>
```

Does anyone have any ideas to work for `<ion-tab>`?

Answer (score 0):

Boiron Shop
      

Note: put unique id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).